# How to create a trigger that waits in Quartz

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I created a job and a trigger

```
var jobKey = new JobKey("awesome job", "awesome group");
q.AddJob<HelloWorldJob>(jobKey, j => j
.WithDescription("my awesome job"));

q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
    .ForJob(jobKey)
    .WithIdentity("HelloWorldJob-trigger")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5))
```

I can call it in a controller like this

```
    var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

    await scheduler.TriggerJob(jobKey);
```

But the problem is that the job starts when application is started

Is there a way to keep trigger idle? so I can trigger it later manually?

I found some similar questions where it was suggested to put in `StartAt` method a date long in future, but this questions were old, maybe there is a more appropriate way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a trigger, call IScheduler.TriggerJob when you want to manually trigger the job. Add the job as durable in scheduler init so it doesn't need to have triggers referring to it.